# How to extract the texts one by one between <p> and span tags

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I am trying to get texts which are named as text1,text2,text3,text4 one by one.

```
<div class="element">
    <p><span>"TEXT1"</span></p>
    <p><span>"TEXT2"<br>"TEXT3"<br>"TEXT4"</span</p>
</div>
```

When I try to use `div.element>p>span` with css selector selenium throws nullpointer exception.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.element>p>span"));
String a = element.getText();
System.out.println("a : "+a);
```

I also tried to get them with for loop but it did not work. Could you please help me?

Comment: First, is there a reason why you need them one at a time? It would be much easier to get everything at one time in an Array and then iterate through the array. Second, your `findElement()` won't work as you expect. It will only get `"TEXT1"` and `"TEXT2"<br>"TEXT3"<br>"TEXT4"`. But we can't solve that until we know if it's possible to get it all in one shot or must it be one at a time.

Comment: after I take them I will send these texts to textbox which is located on the same webpage so I thought that taking one by one could be much practical. I tried List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.element>p>span"));   but still I am getting nullpointer exception.

Comment: I don't believe that the exact code you posted given the HTML will result in a null pointer exception. If the element wasn't found, you would have received a NoSuchElementException. If the element contained no text, you would have received an empty string, not null. Please double check what you posted, run it again and post the exact message you receive (edit it into the question).

Comment: @BaturTürkmen Can you cross check the HTML once, possibly the second `span` tag is not closed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try change your locator with the `xpath`:

```
By.xpath("//*[@class='element']//p")
```

Then collect them in the `List`, use loops and separate them with break lines.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='element']//p"));

for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++) {
    WebElement p = elements.get(i);
    String lines[] = p.getText().split("\\r?\\n");
    for(String line: lines) {
        System.out.println("line :" +line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following  "div > p> span"

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exception means that you are trying to get text from non existing element. So u first ensure that element is found, then try to do something with it.

Also, since your texts are divided by different tags, there is no way to write universal loop here. I'd suggest u to put all text from div container in one string, where it will be texts, divided by special symbols, like /r/n or something. And you can split this string in what you need using [Regex](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285).

Answer (score 0):

To extract the texts *TEXT1*, *TEXT2*, *TEXT3* and *TEXT4* one by one you can use the following [XPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *TEXT1*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='element']/p/span"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"););
  ```
- *TEXT2*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='element']//following-sibling::p[2]")))).toString());
  ```
- *TEXT3*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='element']//following-sibling::p[2]")))).toString());
  ```
- *TEXT4*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='element']//following-sibling::p[2]")))).toString());
  ```